Is there a way to manually adjust objects on a blend path in Illustrator CC?
I am trying to trace a grill where each cut out is on a curved path, in both x and y directions.

The beginning rectangle is slightly different than the end one and when I blend them it interpolates the shape of the intermediate rectangles very well, but the positioning of objects is not great and will get worse at the pattern progresses and the curve is more pronounced.

When I adjust the line the objects sit on to that slight curve the shapes are spaced as follows.

So the solution I am looking for, is to be able to adjust the position of the individual, interpolated objects along the path so I can space them appropriately. (like kerning)
I have access to Corel Draw too, I tried it there, but similar situation, I can only adjust the starting and ending objects.

Why dont you just draw the lines instead and then make the objects out of the grid? So opposite of what you were thinking

.. not as a "live" blend. You would have to expand the blend to adjust more than start/end objects.

@joojaa, the rectangles are offset, stepped, so tracing the lines would not work.

You could try adding a mid-shape.. So you blend 3 shapes rather than just start and end, that should mitigate shape distortion to a degree.

Scott, that is working, still a bit fiddly, but a better and more manageable result than before

Tracing the lines would work, if you expand them afterwards, then you could use the shape builder to make the solid rectangles inside.  I really don't think a blend is practical here at all.

Here's an example - manually drawn lines that were expanded, then the shape builder used to make the rectangles shown in red.

@billy Kerr, I appreciate this, but the lines are not connected like that. There is a slight offset/step between each section.

Yeah but the offset is really easy to deal with the transform effect. Thing is what your asking can be done but that would involve understanding how the bezier interpolation works. (because its nonlinear across the line) Which is the reason you find it fiddly. Alternative for the middle shape is replacing the spine. But well the thing you mention in the answer makes your goal nearly unattainable. But yes theres a more efficient way than what billy kerr was suggesting. that would keep shapes editable.

@AasimAzam - you could add a transform effect to the rectangles, just a very slight rotation to give it a stepped effect. A fraction of a degree would do the trick.

Expand the blend, ungroup and move the paths to the right places.
Before moving anything add to each path a new anchor point to be used as a marker which should be on the blending spine. You must move each path manually. Be sure you have a copy of the blending spine.
OR: take the first given comment seriously. Draw the grill. You can draw at first a rectangular version of it. Distort the grid with envelope distortion.The shearing tool also distorts by skewing the cells, but it doesn't make anything curved.
In the left in the next image a grid is drawn. It contains short brown strokes and long blue strokes. Drawing it was easy, because Object > Transform > Move > Copy can be repeated by pressing Ctrl+D after the first numerically defined move+copy.

In the right the grid is distorted by applying Object > Envelope distortion > Make with 1x1 mesh and rotated. There was no problem to make it fit with your small sample. Deforming a big piece right would be a tough job.
After expanding and ungrouping the envelope distortion the grill is still made of individual strokes:

Twisted wire textures can be got by applying artistic or pattern brushes afterwards. No need to stress the system with heavy textures during the envelope distortion adjustment.

appreciate this, but defeats the purpouse. I want to keep the live blend because I have another 4 grills like this each with a different persective and near accuracy is important.

If your wanted images are different views of  the same grill, a single 3D model of the grill would give them all.

This is a 3d model and exporting it as vectors is hit and miss. Hence why we need to trace manually - its for design registration of a vehicle.

Try to view it as wireframe, hidden lines removed. Print the view as PDF. Open in Illustrator. That trick is used several times in GDSE. Of course, no guarantee your CAD program makes an usable PDF. In some cases there's clipping masks, groups and far too too thick strokes. But they can be fixed easily in Illustrator.

we've tried this before, we had to create frit patterns and it was a mission to get those lines out,

@AasimAzam what cad application are you using? so i can avoid it. Because in the cads i use daily this would be hit every time. Anyway ultimately there is no good solution to this problem. But i mean this isnt really a hard problem if your willing to write a few lines of code.

@joojaa I think its called Creo

@AasimAzam i have never had problems getting vectors out of Creo. In fact i frequently have problems not getting vectors out of creo. But anyway its far far better to do this in creo., its most likely 3 clicks of work.

Okay, so trying to glean information form you comments to try to make a proper answer. Correct me if i'm wrong. So the question is a XY question. In that your asking for solving X but that's just the way you envision to solve the question.
Real solution
Now the real gist is that the thing your truing to get into vectors is already vectors just inside a CAD application. The primary reason is probably that you have no access to the CAD file itself or possibly lack skill in using said CAD application, which in this case is apparently Creo. Though you don't state of its creo elements/direct or Creo parametric.
Now this is a bit of a problem. It can be complicated if you dot have access to the file or if the file is structured a bit weirdly or its not a native Creo file. But also because engineers and the application use a different language when it regards to what you are asking for.
For reasons beyond the scope of this forum it would be much preferable to do this inside Creo if the program is Creo parametric, not only is it capable of doing this. But its capable of doing this for any conceivable situation you could encounter completely automatically after a initial setup in seconds and you would never ever have to do this again even if the model changes whatever the complexity. *
So I would negotiate with the engineering team about this. For the engineering team there is no more work to do a 100 grills than 1 once they know what they need to do and have a setup.
Could this be done in illustrator
Sort of yes. It would be a bit fragile and lot of work for ultimately something that would break if anything ever changes. SO while what your asking certainly would fix your problem to some degree. Its not easily possible. Why?
Well, the interpolation happens in the bezier t parameter space. A bezier is not linear as in the t does not increase easily understandably along the line. So any change in shape would also change how it tensions up. Fortunately you have the easiest iteration of the problem
So a solution was suggested that you use a 3rd item to adjust the tension. This works but youd be much better served with 4 items. Or by adjusting the spine of the blend (spine is the line connecting the blends). The spine is somewhat better as it allows for more degree of control. The spine can be adjusted just like any other spline. This can achieve and bend or adjust the distribution.

Image 1: Bent spine using anchor point tool. Note if you adjust the handles on a straight item it sill adjusts the spread but its harder to see as a picture.
But this is indeed a bit tricky to deal with.
Now if you don't like this there is a alternative option that you do then instead of a blend. What you do is you make a art brush, with a expanded blend. What you then can do is draw a line along one direction. Now you can enter into the brush and drag or arrow nudge individual boxes around. This is more like kerning.
Not sure its any easier.
And finally there is 3rd option draw a line like billy Kerr showed in comments. but make the line serrated then use pathfinder split and offset resulting shape inwards.
Finally
But yeah if i had the Creo model i would just do it in creo since its the least fragile option. Even if Creo sometimes sucks it does not suck here one bit, being probably the best software on the market to handle this particular problem sort of writing your own code which isnt that hard either.
Send this question to the design engineer, he will know what to do.
* Yes i would know how to do this. But it sounds like my day to day work in a way that i would expect to be paid for.

As I mentioned above, the vector exports I have received from the engineering team always break when imported into Illustrator or Corel Draw. It took 3 days to get something that would actually work, and that was a single flattened pane of glass. And they are too busy to spend time on it and I can't get a licence to run Creo on my machine because of cost... its a weird situation.

@AasimAzam  Break how? I have never had this problem and i use Creo with illustrator daily. Too complicated file? It is true that creo can push a magnitude more detail than illustrator can handle. But its not like i must dump all data. But if this is the situation then you just draw all of the things manually. Anyway you dont have time to learn to use Creo its not just a software where you can jump in and figure it out as you go. Imagine how well you know how to use illustrator, if you knew all of the thinbgs illkustrator does, and multiply it by 3 thats the learning curve of creo

@AasimAzam and yes a seat of creo between 2-10 thousand a year depending on what modules you use. So between 10-50 times the cost of your adobe software. But also the file contains all of the companys IP so getting it shared might be a problem

@AasimAzam so unless you were directly hired to draw this by hand by the company, then this is what you do: Tell them that if they are not able to provide you with a technical drawing pdf with only mostly relevant information (so the drawing module is what makes 2d vector images), then they have no legal claim in case of error and they are assuming the entire liability even in unsatisfactory cases (they will understand this because that is how all their mechanical vendors work). No specification no result.
